# viewDidAppear() called before view controller is pushed onto navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have a basic navigation setup in my Storyboard: a vanilla `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. In my main VC I have two buttons that each segue to a `UIViewController` subclass: `LabelledVC`. In the subclass's `viewDidAppear(_:)` method I set the navigation item's `titleView` to a custom image:

```
class LabelledVC: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let logoImage = UIImage(named: "apple")
    let logo = UIImageView(image: logoImage)

    logo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)

    navigationItem.titleView = logo
  }

}
```

For some reason `LabelledVC`'s `viewDidAppear(_:)` method is being called when the app loads (*before* it is pushed onto the navigation stack) which doesn't make any sense to me. You can find the project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5444790/c.zip).

[image]

Comment: In your project your **Viewcontroller** is subclassed by  LabelledVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainVC is inherit from LabelledVC. So when application did show this controller the system calling **viewDidAppear** in **ViewController** but you don't have implementation for this method, so system call this method from parent class.

[image]

One other thing. For your example best place to configure **NavigationItem** is **viewDidLoad** method.

Comment: Sigh... I can't believe I missed that. :-( Thank you.